# Commit showing changes on file that was not added

Tags: git

I have a branch called branchA.  I've been doing some work on it and ran `git pull master` to update it with all the changes in the master branch.  Within branchA, I want to commit two files and they're called py_file1.py and details.sql.  So I do the following:

```
git add py_file1.py
git add details.sql
git commit
```

I then pushed the commit to my remote branch on github.  When I went to checkout the commit on github, I saw both py_file1.py and details.sql, but it was also showing the changes made on py_file2.py that occurred when I pulled from master.  If I never added py_file2.py to be tracked, why are those changes appearing on my commit?

Comment: py_file2.py should be merged file from master branch.

Comment: @EzhilanMahalingam you're right about that.  But that still doesn't mean its tracked and staged for a commit.

Answer (score 0):

`py_file2.py` was indeed tracked, in the `master` branch. Therefore when you merged `master` into `branchA`, it became tracked in `branchA` as well.

That being said, are you saying that it was showing `py_file2.py` as changed in the same commit as as when you added `py_file1.py` and `details.sql`? If that was the case, then you probably pulled, got some conflicts, resolved them, but did not commit *before* you added those two files. In general, you don't want to do that; always commit your merge first before doing any non-merge changes.

Comment: The changes that github is showing on py_file2.py are all correct and expected.  I just thought it wouldn't even show those changes on the commit since I never ran `git add py_file2.py`.  Before committing, I ran `git status` and only py_file1.py and details.sql were the only files listed as staged.

Comment: @Brosef - But just to confirm, the changes to `py_file2.py` were shown on a different commit then the one that shows the changes to the other two files, correct?

Comment: No its all in one commit

Comment: @Brosef - OK, that is odd. Unless you did a `commit --amend`, or ran the `git status` before the pull (and did not immediately commit the merge), I'm not sure what is happening. Is this a public repo by any chance that I could take a look at?

Comment: Actually, I did do a `commit --amend`.  But why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Brosef, when you do a `commit --amend`, you are amending the previous commit, which in this case was the merge commit created when you did a pull. That merge commit contained changes to `py_file2.py`. You didn't see that file when you did `git status` because it was already committed. Then you added your two files to that same commit. I would avoid amending merge commits, btw, as a merge commit should be free of any "non-merge" changes.

Comment: How exactly is a merge commit initiated?  I don't think I've ever used `git merge`.  I did initiate a pull request, which I later cancelled so I could make this last commit.

Comment: @Brosef - `git pull` is actually a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`, so when you did `git pull master` you were actually committing a merge. Now many times `git pull` does not create a merge commit - in those cases it is because your current branch is strictly behind the branch you are merging, so git just "fast forwards" your branch. But that was not the case when you pulled `master`, so a merge commit was initiated.

Comment: Ok this all makes sense now.  You said that a merge commit isn't created when my current branch is strictly behind the branch i'm merging.  Could you clarify that?